# Using spectrum to calculate edges and triangles

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

So I worked out that

> $\sigma(K_6)=\{[-1]^5,[5]\}.$

However how would I use this to calculate the number of edges and triangles in K6?

Comment: If $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then $\text{tr}(A^k)$ is the number of closed walks of length $k$. On the other hand, $\text{tr}(A^k)$ is the sum of $\lambda^k$ as $\lambda$ ranges over the spectrum of $A$. So, how does the number of closed walks of length $2$ relate to the number of edges? How do walks of length $3$ relate to triangles?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure the terminology is confusing me. I was absent for the lecture so I’m a bit lost

Comment: It would help if you could say exactly which terminology you don't understand here

Comment: @Omnomnomnom more so the $\text{tr}(A^k)$ bit and also what’s meant by the sum of $lambda^k$ as$\lambda$ ranges Over the spectrum of $A$

Comment: @lauren Do you know what the trace of a matrix is? Do you know how to take a power of a matrix? If you get that, then $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ is the trace of the matrix $A^k$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of your graph.  About the sum ranging over the spectrum: the point here is that instead of actually calculating $A^k$, we can calculate the trace using the formula
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^k) = \overbrace{(-1)^k + \cdots  + (-1)^k}^{5 \text{ times }} + 5^k.
$$
When he says that "$\lambda$ ranges over the eigenvalues", he means that the values plugged into this sum are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I know the trace is like the diagnosis matrix isn’t it and that’s how I also found the spectrum so do I just plug in numbers to that kind of like the formula you showed below too